# aproveitar apenas o decimal de um double

Tags: java

Como faço pra aproveitar apenas o `decimal` de um `double`?

Estou tentando imprimir a penas a parte decimal de um numero em unidade monetária, ou seja, **R$ 102,33** -> quero imprimir apenas trinta e três centavos.

No momento meu código esta assim:

```
public decimal(double x)
{
    x = 102.33;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tente assim, acho que dá certo!

```
public double decimal(double num){
    return num % 1; //retorna o resto da divisao
}
```

OUUUU

```
public decimal(double x){
    resto = x % 1; //mesma coisa de antes
}
```

como eu não sei se você está fazendo um método comum ou o método construtor então fiz ambas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode multiplicar o valor por `10^n`, em que `n` é o número de casas decimais que você quer mostrar. Depois basta subtrair desse valor a parte inteira, que é `((int) x) * 10^n`.

No seu caso, com `n = 2` e `x = 102.33`, `x*10^n = 10233.00` e `((int) x)*10^n = 10200.00`. Após fazer a subtração `x*10^n - ((int) x)*10^n`, você terá `33.00` como valor e basta converter para inteiro.

Assim o seu código ficaria dessa forma:

```java
public void printDecimal(double x, int n){
  double p = Math.pow(10.0, n);
  int dec = (int) (x*p - ((int) x)*p);
  System.out.println(dec);
}
```

ou se quiser devolver o valor:

```java
public int decimal(double x, int n){
  double p = Math.pow(10.0, n);
  return (int) (x*p - ((int) x)*p);
}
```

Se você quiser o valor no formato `0.33`, basta dividir por `10^n`. Note que você poderia simplesmente não multiplicar por `10^n`, mas iria ter problemas de precisão e a saída para `102.33` seria algo como `0.3299999999999983`. Para evitar esse problema, podemos multiplicar por `10^n`, fazer as operações com os valores inteiros e depois dividir por `10^n`.

```java
public static void printDecimal(double x, int n){
  double p = Math.pow(10.0, n);
  int dec = (int) (x*p - ((int) x)*p);
  System.out.println(dec/p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar fazer uma conversão simples: `(int) num`
Também existe os métodos `Math`:

`Math.floor(num)`: retorna um `int` com o valor do `double` arredondado pra baixo;

`Math.ceil(num)`: a mesma coisa, mas arredondada pra cima;

`Math.round(num)`: pega o `int` mais próximo do `double` escolhido (Por exemplo, o valor 0.9 retorna 1, enquanto 0.4 retorna 0).

Depois disso pode fazer uma subtração simples.
Exemplo:

`double decimal = (num - Math.floor(num));`

É possível fazer o mesmo extraindo o resto da divisão, usando `%`:

`double decimal = (num % 1);`

Ou, se você for um pouco curioso, e goste de fazer as coisas pelo caminho difícil (e pesado, lento, etc.), pode usar um laço de repetição, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
while(num>1){
  // cálculo pra extrair o número
  num--;
}
```

Depende muito o seu objetivo. Se for pra meros fins didáticos, aconselho tentar os três.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também usar Regex para fazer extrair esse valor

```
public int decimal(double num) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=[\\.])[0-9]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Double.toString(num));
    matcher.matches();
    return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Tem algum lugar onde possa estudar o Regex?

Comment: Tem alguns guias legais como esse do https://medium.com/trainingcenter/entendendo-de-uma-vez-por-todas-expressões-regulares-parte-1-introdução-dfe63e289dc3 e sites como o https://www.debuggex.com que desenha o diagrama do seu regex em quanto você escreve  @andrecatete